# How to write correctly arbitrary fractions in Unicode?

Tags: unicode

How do i write correctly arbitrary fractions according to the Unicode standard for the OpenType feature `frac` ?

My use case is:
I write data in a text document(UTF-8) and have self written program which creates html markup from that file.

Different sources give different instructions.
How should i write the numerator and denominator? With normal Digits or Super- and Subscript?
The separation of numerator and denominator should be written with a FRACTION SLASH (U+2044), ins’t it?

Explanatory Edit:
I primary want to know how to **write** a fraction according to Unicode standard in a *plaintext* file. No additional markup.
With the correct fraction i can test which font supports these in html.
Even if I am unsure how the css font settings affect this topic [OpenType_fonts_guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_fonts/OpenType_fonts_guide#the_font_features). The linked example simply uses digits and Solidus but enables a specific OpenType feature.

Comment: Unicode will not have arbitrary fractions, only "common" ones. How you represent them in text and convert from one to the other will depend on your tools. Personally I would say that proper decimal numbers (0.000125) can display data more recognisably and consistently than a fractional notation.

Comment: What have you tried? Is the issue converting to HTML Markup, or have you found that the codes you've tried aren't working, or something else? If different sources give different info, have you tried any of the instructions those sources give? What were the outcomes?

Comment: one problem with the special unicode glyphs is that they sometimes drop out silently: when moving the text from one form to anothe (e.g. from word processor to DTP layout), the only trace of them might be a small space. when fractions matter, it is better to see a typo/glitch/no-op glyph than nothing.

Comment: @music2myear the variety on input parameters, fonts that doesn’t implement some things and that i don't know how a fraction *should* look with particular font, makes difficult to find the correct solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The post
[How to display the fraction 15/16 nicely in Unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55033436/how-to-display-the-fraction-15-16-nicely-in-unicode)
has answers that cover well many aspects of the problem.

The [answer by CharlotteBuff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55034877/165358)
says this :

> The “proper” way of composing arbitrary vulgar fractions in Unicode is
> to not use the subscript and superscript digits at all, but to utilise
> the special properties of the character U+2044 FRACTION SLASH. You
> would simply type the regular ASCII digits and separate them with the
> slash like so: 15⁄16. The rendering engine will then automatically
> select the correct forms of the numbers, producing a clean, uniform
> look.
>
> I put the word ‘proper’ in quotation marks because this method is not
> guaranteed to be supported on all systems, and some that do support it
> do so incorrectly or incompletely. If you absolutely need to make sure
> that 100% of recipients regardless of system will definitely see
> something that looks more or less right, I would therefore still
> (begrudgingly) recommend using the preformatted subscripts and
> superscripts as a substitute.

The [answer by user8022331](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55033920/165358)
explains some more this mess:

> This is indeed a font issue, however the problem arises from the fact
> that, in Unicode, `¹`, `²`, and `³` belong to the *Latin-1 Supplement
> block*, while the other superscript digits belong to the *Superscripts
> and Subscripts block*, and some font substitution occurs.
>
> Please see [Why the display of Unicode characters for superscripted
> digits are not at the same
> height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663251/why-the-display-of-unicode-characters-for-superscripted-digits-are-not-at-the-sa)
> for extra details; it is tagged as iOS, but I have the same problem on
> macOS too.

The [answer by js2010](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70842803/165358)
link to the website
[Unicode Fraction Creator](https://lights0123.com/fractions/)
which may help you with constructing such fractions.

However, whatever you do, you're limited by the tool that you use
for composing the text and to its limitations.

Comment: 'Special properties of the fraction slash'? No sign of that working on my machine here. I do see the height discrepancy between the two different font sets of superscript, but not if I use it in the SE answer space. That renders just fine.

Comment: Unicode is very simple to describe, but exceedingly complex to fully implement, and not all implementations are full-featured or correct. You need to either avoid relying on the finer points, or ensure by test that it works right on your target devices(s).

Answer (score 1):

You're kind of between a rock & a hard place…

In order below - actual unicode; composite made from superscript, fraction slash & subscript; regular numbers & fraction slash; regular numbers & ordinary 'divide' solidus.

¾ ³⁄₄ 3⁄4 3/4

Only the true unicode really works properly, so unless you can dictate kerning/tracking per character, it's not going to look as good made out of individual parts.
Most people, though, would find the last examples made with just 'regular' characters acceptable.

An alternative might be LaTex, but that's not something I'm particularly familiar with.

The issue with font substitution in superscript may depend on what you're viewing with. I don't see it at all in SE [on Mac Safari & Chrome].
I wonder what others see here…

'live' rendered text
superscript ¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹⁰
subscript ₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉₀

screenshots
Safari

> [image]

Chrome

> [image]